# Question mark not recognized with path function

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I'm working on a django web app. I'm trying to implement a search field that would "communicate" with the url.

I want from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract/` that when I enter an id in the search field, it redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract/id`.

The problem is that when using the search field, it redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract/?search=id` which is not really a problem. But when I try to define the urlpattern, it doesn't 'recognize' the question mark in the url. The consequence being that I can't access to the right template.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('?search=<id_contract>/', app_views.view_contract),
    path('', app_views.contract, name='my_contract'),
]
```

I see two possible solutions : either I would try to find a way to remove that question mark, but I haven't really found where to do it so I would much appreciate your help!

Second option consists in using regex but what I've tried so far didn't work:

```
re_path(r'.+\?.*'+'search'+'(?P<id_contract>)/$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses request path to figure out which of url patterns to apply. Path is everything after your `http://domain:port/` part of URL and before `?arg1=value1&arg2=value2` part. In your case path is `contract/` in both cases.

To handle parameters after `?`, you should write specific code in your endpoint, using `request.args` or something. In your case, however, I think you should just stop using default search form and write some JavaScript to make it navigate to `contract/id` as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contract/(?P<id_contract>\d+)/$', app_views.view_contract),
]
```

In this case, your view would have to look like this:

```
def view_contract(request, id_contract):
    # your code
```

And the endpoint would look like http://localhost:8000/contract/1234/ where **1234** is the id of the contract.

Comment: I would recomend this as the real answer. It does the same thing you want and it's more of an "official" url than using GET queries.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the query parameters (the part after the question mark `?`) use [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), which behaves like a python dictionary.

In your case, `?search=id` will result in `request.GET` containing `{'search': 'id'}`. You could use something along the lines of the following code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', app_views.contract, name='my_contract'),
]

def view_contract(request):
    search_value = request.GET.get('search', '')

    # do something if it meets certain conditions
    if search_value == 'id':
        # here you could do your redirect if its still needed
        return redirect('...')

    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'search': search_value})
```